# Pushing Certificates for ios 8

Tags: ios, mdm

Please could someone shed some light on the following question , I have about 21 ios8.3 devices in the field and I have an app on it with a certificate about to expire . I have been able to send new certificates using the apple mdm but this now only works on ios 7 only and its proving to be quite difficult to get these apps working with no work around of being able to send new certificates from the MDM to these devices. HELP

Comment: Can you recompile the app (using the new certificate) and push the new version of the app?

Comment: What type of certificate? Development or something else?

Comment: Distribution cert and provisioning profile .